# How to print() to logs in the release mode in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, debugging, logging, release

My web app has a problem that only manifests in profile and release builds (a widget is not rendering properly, producing only gray). I want to add some print() statements to help figure out what the problem is, but print() doesn't log anything to VSCode debug output window in profile/release builds.

Any ideas how to fix that?

What other techniques can I use to diagnose release-only problems?

Thx

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways of doing it:

1. Use the following command

   ```
   flutter logs
   ```
2. Use [`logger`](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) package.

   > The default implementation (DevelopmentFilter) shows all logs with level >= Logger.level while in debug mode. In release mode all logs are omitted.

   In order to show all logs even in release mode, create your own `LogFilter` like this:

   ```dart
   class MyFilter extends LogFilter {
     @override
     bool shouldLog(LogEvent event) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   ```

   **Usage:**

   ```dart
   void foo() {
     var logger = Logger(filter: MyFilter());
     logger.d('message');
   }
   ```
3. Use `print` statement (not sure if this works on web)

Answer (score 1):

Showing grey in release while working well in production sounds like wrongly using the Expanded() widget.
You should use Expanded only within a Column, Row or Flex.
For some reason Flutter developers thought it would be a good way to make it stand out...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting any logs in release mode, try plugging your device in via `cable`. I was using wireless debugging, which is why I couldn't get any logs.